# why is my component getting rendered once but then failing on refresh

Tags: reactjs

i am working on small  react assignment,

following is my component code. So my component is getting rendered once but then it just fails.i'll attach the screenshots too, can some one please explain what is happening?is there an error in the code or is it because of some rate limiting in API i am using?

```
import React from 'react'

const Menu = ({events}) => {
    console.log(events);
    return (
        <div>
            {events.map((event)=>{
                return(  <div key={event.category}>
                    <h3>{event.category}</h3>
                </div>)
            })}
        </div>

    )
}

export default Menu
```

[code working image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9iUb.png)

[error on same code pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ithqh.png)

parent component code

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Menu from './components/Menu';

function App() {
  const [isLoading,setISLoading] = useState(true);
  const[events,setEvents] = useState()

  const getEvents = async()=>{
    const response = await fetch('https://allevents.s3.amazonaws.com/tests/categories.json');
    const eventsData =await response.json()
    setISLoading(false);
    setEvents(eventsData);
  }
  useEffect(()=>getEvents(),[]);
  return (
    isLoading?<h1>Loading...</h1>:<Menu events = {events}/>


  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: There is the reason: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects
`If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always works.`
Simply, you should remove the second argument in useEffect.

Comment: so you are telling me to remove 2nd argument from my useEffect?  i tried it and the error still prevails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the parent component of Menu which is supplying events is not using any loading state. So when the component is mounted and starts making ajax calls, events is undefined. You need to put a condition over there like this:

```
import React from 'react'

const Menu = ({events}) => {
    console.log(events);
    return events ? (
        <div>
            {events.map((event)=>{
                return(  <div key={event.category}>
                    <h3>{event.category}</h3>
                </div>)
            })}
        </div>

    ) : null
}

export default Menu
```

Comment: i edited the question to put the parent component code

Comment: oh yeah your solution worked,also me editing my parent code by setting is loading false after setevents worked,thanx you so Much!